# Is there a way to burn a specific SPL Token quantity within a wallet while simultaneously minting a different SPL Token quantity within that wallet?

Tags: transactions, spl-token-program, mint, burn

I read through the documentation in the SPL Token program and I am not clearly seeing if there is a way to have a single transaction perform a simultaneous burn and mint operation for various tokens and quantities. Is there a program that makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Solana, a *transaction* is arbitrary sequence of *instructions*.

There is nothing stopping you from grouping a burn instruction and mint instruction together in one transaction.

The transaction is guaranteed to be atomic, i.e. either both instructions will be executed successfully, or none.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a special program to do this. You can create a burn instruction and a mint instruction, and put them into the same transaction.

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#createBurnInstruction

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#createMintToInstruction

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to actually enforce that the tokens are burned before allowing the mint to occur, you would need to implement this as a program that CPIs into the spl token program

Comment: Note to self: a CPI is a Cross-Program Invocation: https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/CPIs.html